# WebSphere 8.5, Why AdminApp returns "exception information: websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException"

Tags: unix, deployment, websphere, jython

I have a very simply Jython script over Unix. It was working perfectly during WebSphere 7 and now, after we upgraded to WAS 8.5 it isn't working anymore. Obviously, I changed the path to point to WAS8.5. I spent the whole day struglling to find the reason for this falling and I am completely stuck. The exception descrition doesn't help much.

From a JCL JOB I call the Jython script.
/WebSphere/was85/dtl85cel/ledm85nd/DeploymentManager/profiles/default/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /WebSphereDevelopment/scripts/dtl/WAS85/Install.jy

The Jython script is really simple.
Basically, I call AdminApp.install("myEAR path", ...with the options below:

-nopreCompileJSPs -installed.ear.destination /WebSphereDevelopment/MYAPP/dtl/curr/deployment/ -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -nodeployejb -appname DVL-MYAPP -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -nodeployws -validateinstall warn -processEmbeddedConfig -filepermission .*.dll=755#.* *.so=755#.*.a=755#.*.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink -contextroot / -MapModulesToServers ÝÝ MyApp MyApp.war,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=dtl85cel,node=wleMyAppa,server=WLEMYAPP¨¨
)

The error log is:

WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/WebSphereDevelopment/scripts dtl/MYAPP/MYAPP_DTL_DEPLOY.jy"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: com.ibm.websphere.management.appliccation.client.AppDeploymentException:  ÝRoot exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Deploying /WebSphere/was85/dtl85cel/ledm85nd/DeploymentManager/profiles/d java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deploying /WebSphere/wa s85/dtl85cel/ledm85nd/DeploymentManager/profiles/default/temp/app69105293327198772690.ear failed.

Comment: Where are the 'Ý' chars coming from?

Comment: What does the wsadmin.traceout file say?

Comment: Aguibert, after I removed "Y", I got this error:
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/WebSphereDevelopment/scripts/
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 30, in ?
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WASX7122E: Expected "-"  not found.

Comment: Bkail, strange as it can be, I didn't find any recent logs in wsadmin.traceout. I looked at:

/WebSphere/was85/dtl85cel/wleMyAppa/AppServer/profiles/default/logs

and the last logs are very old: 

000263,[9/24/15 11:47:35:314 CDT] 00000001 AdminControlC W   WASX7072E:
000264,[9/24/15 11:47:35:650 CDT] 00000001 AbstractShell A   WASX7091I:
000265,[9/24/15 11:47:35:980 CDT] 00000001 FileRepositor A   ADMR0010I:

Comment: Do you know how to find the recent logs on wsadmin.traceout in Websphere 8.5 running over mainframe?

Answer (score 2):

Turn on tracing under wsadmin.properties: 
com.ibm.ws.scripting.traceString

Comment: Do you know how I enable this property safely in Unix/Mainframe? I am getting this warnning when I open the file via UdList utility:
"Truncation warning. The data you are editing is variable length data with at least one record that ends with a blank. Saving the data will result in removal of any trailing blanks from all records. You can issue the PRESERVE ON command if you don't want the blanks removed."
I found 000080,#com.ibm.ws.scripting.traceString=com.ibm.*=all so I guess that just removing "#" will turn on tracing but I am afraid to corrupt the file as the warning drove me to understand

Comment: Even after I took out the "#" I am still not getting a single message in wsadmin.traceout. Is there any other thing I must do in order to print the exceptions? I am stuck with the error log WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/WebSphereDevelopment/scripts/ Traceback (innermost last): File "<string>", line 30, in ? java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WASX7122E: Expected "-" not found. Is there somewhere in my options a missed "-"?

Comment: Please check this IBM link:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_propscript.html

Side note: Remember to disable the tracing after you have done troubleshooting, It might make running wsadmin.sh slow as it will be logging lot of details.

Comment: I carefully read the IBM link but unfortunately I still don't know how to get the exceptions logged in somewhere. The link tells about three level of traces. The first certainly is the one I did whithout success.
(...located in the profile_root/properties... called wsadmin.properties). The second is about user.home property and the third level is a properties file that is pointed to by the WSADMIN_PROPERTIES environment variable. How can I find the last two levels in Unix/Mainframe and turn them on?